# Pytorch: The size of tensor a (24) must match the size of tensor b (48) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: pytorch, feature-extraction, image-compression

Below code works fine and generate proper results.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

from modules import ConvLSTMCell, Sign


class EncoderCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EncoderCell, self).__init__()

        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(
            3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.rnn1 = ConvLSTMCell(
            64,
            256,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn2 = ConvLSTMCell(
            256,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn3 = ConvLSTMCell(
            512,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)

    def forward(self, input, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3):
        x = self.conv(input)

        hidden1 = self.rnn1(x, hidden1)
        x = hidden1[0]

        hidden2 = self.rnn2(x, hidden2)
        x = hidden2[0]

        hidden3 = self.rnn3(x, hidden3)
        x = hidden3[0]

        return x, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3


class Binarizer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Binarizer, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(512, 32, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.sign = Sign()

    def forward(self, input):
        feat = self.conv(input)
        x = F.tanh(feat)
        return self.sign(x)


class DecoderCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DecoderCell, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            32, 512, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
        self.rnn1 = ConvLSTMCell(
            512,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn2 = ConvLSTMCell(
            128,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn3 = ConvLSTMCell(
            128,
            256,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=3,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn4 = ConvLSTMCell(
            64,
            128,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=3,
            bias=False)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            32, 3, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)

    def forward(self, input, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4):
        x = self.conv1(input)

        hidden1 = self.rnn1(x, hidden1)
        x = hidden1[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden2 = self.rnn2(x, hidden2)
        x = hidden2[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden3 = self.rnn3(x, hidden3)
        x = hidden3[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden4 = self.rnn4(x, hidden4)
        x = hidden4[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        x = F.tanh(self.conv2(x)) / 2
        return x, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4
```

Now i have changed in self.con and add pretrained resent with layer. Now it shows tensor mismatched error after training. All things are same just add this line in code. I put ** in those line

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models


from modules import ConvLSTMCell, Sign


class EncoderCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EncoderCell, self).__init__()

        #self.conv = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)

        **resConv = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        resConv.layer4 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.conv = resConv.layer4**


        self.rnn1 = ConvLSTMCell(
            64,
            256,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn2 = ConvLSTMCell(
            256,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn3 = ConvLSTMCell(
            512,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=2,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)

    def forward(self, input, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3):

        x = self.conv(input)

        hidden1 = self.rnn1(x, hidden1)
        x = hidden1[0]

        hidden2 = self.rnn2(x, hidden2)
        x = hidden2[0]

        hidden3 = self.rnn3(x, hidden3)
        x = hidden3[0]

        return x, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3


class Binarizer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Binarizer, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(512, 32, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.sign = Sign()

    def forward(self, input):
        feat = self.conv(input)
        x = F.tanh(feat)
        return self.sign(x)


class DecoderCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DecoderCell, self).__init__()

        **resConv = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        resConv.layer4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 512, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.conv1 = resConv.layer4**

        self.rnn1 = ConvLSTMCell(
            512,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn2 = ConvLSTMCell(
            128,
            512,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=1,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn3 = ConvLSTMCell(
            128,
            256,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=3,
            bias=False)
        self.rnn4 = ConvLSTMCell(
            64,
            128,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1,
            hidden_kernel_size=3,
            bias=False)

        **resConv2 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        resConv2.layer4 = nn.Conv2d(32, 3, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
        self.conv2 = resConv2.layer4**

    def forward(self, input, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4):
        x = self.conv1(input)

        hidden1 = self.rnn1(x, hidden1)
        x = hidden1[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden2 = self.rnn2(x, hidden2)
        x = hidden2[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden3 = self.rnn3(x, hidden3)
        x = hidden3[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        hidden4 = self.rnn4(x, hidden4)
        x = hidden4[0]
        x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

        x = F.tanh(self.conv2(x)) / 2
        return x, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it a wrong way, some explanation is,

```
    **resConv = models.resnet50(pretrained=True) # you are reading a model
```

now you are replacing the layer in that model with newly initialized layer. Secondly, layer4 in resnet50 is a sequential block containing multiple layers. Use print to see exact the layers in model.

```
    resConv.layer4 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
```

here you are using new layer.

```
self.conv = resConv.layer4**
```

As per your query regarding usage of pretrained layer, you should do it like this,

```
resConv = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
print(resConv) #see the layer which you want to use
self.conv = resConv.conv1 # replace conv1 with that layer
# note: conv1 is the name of first conv layer in resnet
```

To add to this, I would also recommend acquiring and adding this layer (or the weights and biases) outside of the object initialization. Something like:

```
enc = EncoderCell()
resnet50 = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
```

and then either

```
enc.conv = resnet50.conv1
```

or more ideally

```
enc.conv.load_state_dict(resnet50.layer1.state_dict())
```

The reason being, calling state_dict() on a nn.Module class creates a clone of the parameters (weights and biases in this case) which can be loaded via nn.Module.load_state_dict() method as long as the two instances of nn.Module share the same shape. So you get the pretrained weights and they are completely detached from the pretrained model. Then you can get rid of the pretrained model since it could be rather large in memory.

```
del resnet50
```

Comment: If i replace original conv1 layer with resnet layer1 then what is the difference? both becomes same layers.

Comment: I dont understand, can you explain your query

Comment: I just implemented your code but it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a potential improvement to the other answer, but to address the errors you are getting I am answering here also. If the code runs before your edits, and the layer you are trying to change is the same shape as the previous one, then my guess is that it may have to do with the computational graph that is formed from creating the resnet50 object. I would recommended the approach I mentioned in my edit to the other answer, but I will state it here again (note, this assumes you keep the code as it was originally):

```
# instantiate you encoder (repeat these steps with the decoder as well)
enc = EncoderCell()
# get the pretrained model
resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
# load the state dict into the regular conv layer
enc.conv.load_state_dict(resnet50.layer4.state_dict())
```

This should load the pretrained weights and biases from the resnet50 model into your conv layer, and this can be done to the decoder conv layer as well as long as they all share the same shape.

To do more testing with your mismatch error I would recommend either using a debugger or print statements in the forward() method of the models to see the shape of the tensor after each layer is applied, like so

```
def forward(self, input, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4):
    print(x.size())
    x = self.conv1(input)
    print(x.size())
    hidden1 = self.rnn1(x, hidden1)
    x = hidden1[0]
    x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

    hidden2 = self.rnn2(x, hidden2)
    x = hidden2[0]
    x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

    hidden3 = self.rnn3(x, hidden3)
    x = hidden3[0]
    x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

    hidden4 = self.rnn4(x, hidden4)
    x = hidden4[0]
    x = F.pixel_shuffle(x, 2)

    x = F.tanh(self.conv2(x)) / 2
    return x, hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, hidden4
```

and of course you can put the print statements where ever else in the forward method. I would also highly recommend a debugger; pycharm makes this quite easy, and also makes it easy to see the state of variables in scientific mode beside the python console it gives. It might be worth looking up ways to calculate size of variables after they pass through certain layers like convolutional layers. This is well understood and formulas exist to calculate the size of the dimensions based on the initial size, the filter size, stride width, and padding.